# Html Range slider with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have recently been playing around with styling the html `range` slider.

I came across a pen on CodePen that has some really great designs.

This is the source code from one.

**HTML:**

```
<input type="range" data-idx="1">
```

**CSS:**

```
html {
  background: #393939;
}

input[type='range'] {
  display: block;
  margin: 2.5em auto;
  border: solid .5em transparent;
  padding: 0;
  width: 15.5em;
  height: 1em;
  border-radius: .25em;
  background: transparent;
  font-size: 1em;
  cursor: pointer;
}
input[type='range'], input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-runnable-track, input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  width: 15.5em;
  height: 0.5em;
  border-radius: 0.25em;
  background: #fff;
}
.js input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  background: linear-gradient(#e44e4f, #e44e4f) no-repeat #fff;
}
input[type='range']::-moz-range-track {
  width: 15.5em;
  height: 0.5em;
  border-radius: 0.25em;
  background: #fff;
}
.js input[type='range']::-moz-range-track {
  background: linear-gradient(#e44e4f, #e44e4f) no-repeat #fff;
}
input[type='range']::-ms-track {
  border: none;
  width: 15.5em;
  height: 0.5em;
  border-radius: 0.25em;
  background: #fff;
  color: transparent;
}
input[type='range']::-ms-fill-lower {
  border-radius: 0.25em;
  background: #e44e4f;
}
input[type='range']:nth-of-type(1)::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  background-size: 50% 100%;
}
input[type='range']:nth-of-type(1)::-moz-range-track {
  background-size: 50% 100%;
}
input[type='range']:nth-of-type(1)::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  margin-top: -0.125em;
  border: none;
  width: 0.75em;
  height: 0.75em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.125em #333;
  background: #fff;
}
input[type='range']:nth-of-type(1)::-moz-range-thumb {
  border: none;
  width: 0.75em;
  height: 0.75em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.125em #333;
  background: #fff;
}
input[type='range']:nth-of-type(1)::-ms-thumb {
  border: none;
  width: 0.75em;
  height: 0.75em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.125em #333;
  background: #fff;
}
input[type='range']:nth-of-type(1)::-ms-tooltip {
  display: none;
}
input[type='range']:focus {
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.25em #e44e4f;
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
var s = document.createElement('style'), 
    r = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=range]'), 
    prefs = ['webkit-slider-runnable', 'moz-range'], 
    styles = [], 
    l = prefs.length
    n = r.length;

document.body.appendChild(s);

var getTrackStyleStr = function(el) {
  var str = '', 
      j = el.dataset.idx, 
      min = el.min || 0, 
      perc = (el.max) ? ~~(100*(el.value - min)/(el.max - min)) : el.value, 
      val = perc + '% 100%';

  for(var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    str += '.js input[type=range]:nth-of-type(' + j + ')::-' + prefs[i] + '-track{background-size:' + val + '}';
  }

  return str;
};

var getTipStyleStr = function(el) {
  var str = '.js input[type=range]:nth-of-type(' + el.dataset.idx + ') /deep/ #thumb:after{content:"' + el.value + '%"}';

  return str;
};

for(var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  styles.push('');

  r[i].addEventListener('input', function() {    
    styles[this.dataset.idx] = getTrackStyleStr(this);
    if(this.classList.contains('tip')) {
      styles[this.dataset.idx] += getTipStyleStr(this);
    }

    s.textContent = styles.join('');
  }, false);
}
```

This works great for one range element but if I try adding more range elements on the same page, and change the data attribute to `data-idx="2"` it will not work, the first range will control them all.

How can I adjust the code to make each range work independently?

Here is a **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wrahef1p/)** of the code I'm using, for some reason the javascript isn't working on there at all, but it's works fine on codepen? Hmm...

Here is the original **[Codepen](http://codepen.io/thebabydino/pen/azKqWa)**

Comment: It does not work on codepen with multiple idx elements either

Comment: Yeah I know, that's why I needing to adjust the javascript.

Comment: Ok I fixed it! not a big deal ... just some strange code from babydino with those idx and /deep/ stuff rsrss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**SOLUTION**](http://jsbin.com/dowuko/4/edit?html,css,js,output)

```js
var r = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=range]'), 
    prefs = ['webkit-slider-runnable', 'moz-range'], 
    styles = [], 
    l = prefs.length,
    n = r.length;

var getTrackStyleStr = function(el, j) {
  var str = '', 
      min = el.min || 0, 
      perc = (el.max) ? ~~(100*(el.value - min)/(el.max - min)) : el.value, 
      val = perc + '% 100%';

  el.previousElementSibling.textContent = el.value;
  
  for(var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    str += "input[type=range][data-rangeId='" + j + "']::-" + prefs[i] + '-track{background-size:' + val + '} ';
  }
  return str;
};

var setDragStyleStr = function(evt) {
  var trackStyle = getTrackStyleStr(evt.target, this); 
  styles[this].textContent = trackStyle;
};

for(var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  var s = document.createElement('style');
  document.body.appendChild(s);
  styles.push(s);
  r[i].setAttribute('data-rangeId', i);
  r[i].addEventListener('input', setDragStyleStr.bind(i));
}
```

```css
html {
  background: #393939;
}

div {
  margin: 2.5em auto;
}

input[type='range'] {
  display: block;
  margin: 0.2em auto;
  border: solid .5em transparent;
  padding: 0;
  width: 15.5em;
  height: 1em;
  border-radius: .25em;
  background: transparent;
  font-size: 1em;
  cursor: pointer;
}
input[type='range'], 
input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-runnable-track, 
input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  width: 15.5em;
  height: 0.5em;
  border-radius: 0.25em;
  background: #fff;
}
input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  background: linear-gradient(#e44e4f, #e44e4f) no-repeat #fff;
}
input[type='range']::-moz-range-track {
  width: 15.5em;
  height: 0.5em;
  border-radius: 0.25em;
  background: #fff;
}
input[type='range']::-moz-range-track {
  background: linear-gradient(#e44e4f, #e44e4f) no-repeat #fff;
}
input[type='range']::-ms-track {
  border: none;
  width: 15.5em;
  height: 0.5em;
  border-radius: 0.25em;
  background: #fff;
  color: transparent;
}
input[type='range']::-ms-fill-lower {
  border-radius: 0.25em;
  background: #e44e4f;
}
input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  background-size: 0% 100%;
}
input[type='range']::-moz-range-track {
  background-size: 0% 100%;
}
input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  margin-top: -0.125em;
  border: none;
  width: 0.75em;
  height: 0.75em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.125em #333;
  background: #fff;
}
input[type='range']::-moz-range-thumb {
  border: none;
  width: 0.75em;
  height: 0.75em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.125em #333;
  background: #fff;
}
input[type='range']::-ms-thumb {
  border: none;
  width: 0.75em;
  height: 0.75em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.125em #333;
  background: #fff;
}
input[type='range']::-ms-tooltip {
  display: none;
}
input[type='range']:focus {
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.25em #e44e4f;
}

output[for='range'] {
  font-family: "Lucida Grande","Lucida Sans Unicode", Tahoma, Sans-Serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <output for="range">0</output>
  <input type="range" value="0">
</div>
<div>
  <output for="range">0</output>
  <input type="range" value="0">
</div>
<div>
  <output for="range">0</output>
  <input type="range" value="0">
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, this is working perfectly. Yeah babydino has quite a few examples of sliders and she uses the same javascript for most of them, it was confusing me how she had wrote some of it and using the `data-idx`. Great job on simplifying it though, thanks! :)

Comment: Also, do you have any idea why the code wasn't working when I copied it into a jsfiddle?

Comment: Just been testing your code and noticed if you put one of the inputs into a div tag for example, the code breaks. Could you possibly update your answer with a fix for this?

Comment: I was meaning if you wanted to put each input into a separate div, like this - http://jsfiddle.net/wrahef1p/4/

Comment: done! http://jsbin.com/lasabi/3/edit?html,js,output ... no css changes .. just modified the js

Comment: Great! Which parts did you modify to do that?

Comment: i had to add a data attribute (pretty much like idx from babydino - but i used js instead of html) and use multiple css attribute selectors ... that's mainly the `str += "input[type=range][data-rangeId='" + j + "']::-" +` part of the code

Comment: I'm still learning javascript so sorry if this is a silly question but couldn't you use something like `(this)` so it would only effect the slider that you're controlling instead of giving each slider an id?

Comment: that's the most common way to manipulate an element css, but the range pseudo elements (in this case "webkit-slider-runnable-track or moz-range-track") cannot be accessed through js yet ... great question

Comment: Oh ok, so I have added a simple function to your existing code to get the output from the slider, how could I bind this to the slider thumb, so it would be in a small bubble/box above the thumb. Here's what I have so far - http://jsbin.com/zijazabune/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: easy ... http://jsbin.com/dowuko/4/edit?css,output ... I updated the answer ... 3 chances: html: output before the input ... css: `output[for='range'] {...` and js: `el.previousElementSibling.textContent = el.value;`

Comment: Hmm.. that's not exactly what I was trying to explain, what I mean't was the output would move with the slider thumb, so as you slide the thumb backwards and forwards the output would slide with it

Comment: Like this for example, this is the effect I'm trying to achieve - http://codepen.io/yannicvanveen/pen/HtvbI

Comment: ok .. dude u r a picky one rsrssss ... http://jsbin.com/dowuko/6/edit?css,js,output ... JS: `el.previousElementSibling.style.left = (el.value/110 * el.scrollWidth) + 'px';` CSS: `position: relative;
  width: 18.5em; margin: 0 auto;`

Comment: I'm a designer / front end developer so I'm very picky when it comes to the smallest details :) I just want to say that I really appreciate you talking the time to make the alteration I'm looking for, so thanks a bunch! One thing I did notice though is that as you slide the thumb along, the output doesn't always stay perfectly inline with the thumb? Think you could do a fix for that? You seem to be very experienced so I'm sure that wouldn't be too tricky for you?

Comment: in order to adjust the position you just need to change the css width of the output and the 110 value in the expression: `el.previousElementSibling.style.left = (el.value/110 * el.scrollWidth) + 'px';` ... it seems exactly in place for me, so I will leave this one in your hands! glhf

Answer (score 0):

Jquery UI offers some functional sliders that can be used in multiple instances on a page.  You don't have to write or modify as much code to use them as above.  Unless you are trying to avoid jquery, this may be a better option for you.

Here is a link to the [multiple sliders demo](http://jqueryui.com/slider/#multiple-vertical).

The approach used for multiple sliders relies of course on jquery, but given markup such as:

```
<div id="eq">
    <span>88</span>
    <span>77</span>
    <span>55</span>
    <span>33</span>
    <span>40</span>
    <span>45</span>
    <span>70</span>
</div>
```

A simple .each statement handles setting them all up.

```
$( "#eq > span" ).each(function() {
  // read initial values from markup and remove that
  var value = parseInt( $( this ).text(), 10 );
  $( this ).empty().slider({
    value: value,
    range: "min",
    animate: true,
    orientation: "vertical"
  });
});
```

**Edit:** As per comments below, if you want to add tool-tips / hints, you have to roll your own.  Here's a brief example from some code I wrote last year.  It has some specific behaviors that fit the needs of my users, but this should give you an idea. The id "hintrow" refers to a table row on a grid that contained my slider.  Through experimentation, you can probably find the best place relative to your various sliders to append this.  It will get positioned so you only want a dom node to append it to.

```
function drawExtCues(){
    z = 200;
    $('#hintrow').append('<div id="hintContainer" style="position:relative"></div>');
    for(h in rowobjects){
        z++;
        $('#hintContainer').append('<div title="' + rowobject[h].property1 + '" class="' + rowobject[h].property2+ ' ui-slider-range hint" style="z-index:' + z +';">' + rowobject[h].property1+ '</div>');
    }
    $('.hint').mouseover(function(){
            hintMouseOver();                
        });     
  }

  function hintMouseOver(){
    $('.hint').addClass('hintInspect',500);
    $('.hint').unbind('mouseover');
    $('.hint').click(function(){
            $J('.hint').removeClass('hintInspect',500);
            $J('.hint').mouseover(function(){hintMouseOver();})
        });                 

  }
```

Note the z++.  This was used to ensure my tool-tips would stack. Since we made them click to dismiss in our case, this worked well.  You don't have to do this, but if you don't use a click to dismiss, you might want to bind a timeout to clear the tool tip for you.

The hintMouseOver function does some house cleaning, like unbinding itself to prevent repeat calls.  It is rebound after the click event to dismiss the tool tip is fired.  This is just the behavior my client wanted.  You could do a lot of things here.  The class hintInspect is basically the style rules for how your tool-tip will appear.  You can make it look any way you like.  I think I just used a simple black outline with grey background.

Comment: How easy would it be to style the slider? I'm wanting to use similar styles to what I posted above. I'm also needing to get an output from the slider, I'm wanting to expand onto this and have a bubble above the slider that displays the value.

Comment: You can use the jquery ui theme roller or you can just write your own stylesheet.  The inserted slider control has predictable class names that you can inspect to write your own style rules, which I've done on my own, and hence suggest you use the jquery themes as they look nice out of the box with little work.  I think there's even a silver on black one like your fiddle.

Comment: Check out http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/ the theme gallery.    I had to roll my own tool tip (bubble with value) when I used this.  It wasn't terribly difficult but did take some experimentation.  The API documentation shows you how to read the values or bind events to the change / click / drag so you can perform a number of bindings.

Comment: Since you have already overcome this problem, do you think you could possibly mock me up a demo on jsfiddle with code you used? Would really appreciate that. :)

Comment: Tool tip example added.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to expand on that, I'll definitely look into how I could include something like this, but for now rafaelcastrocouto has gave me a working example of what I need :)